# javascript enter key redirection in text box

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser, window.open

I have a simple text box, and I wish to make the page redirected when I type something in it.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="window.open('http://www.example.com', '_self');" />
```

However when I press `Enter` key in this textbox, it does not go to the new page. But it does when I press keys like A, B, 1, 2... This happens in Chrome, Firefox and IE9 for me, not in IE8.

But when I place an `alert` function in it, yet `Enter` key pressed, after I dismiss the alert box, it redirects successfully.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="alert();window.open('http://www.example.com', '_self');" />
```

It does in all browsers.

Can anyone explain this browser behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I think this behavior is because you have not set `return false`.
try like this in your code:

```
function navigate()
{
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  window.event.returnValue=false;
}
```

in HTML use like this:

```
   <input type="text" onkeydown="navigate();" />
```

Hope this will help.
 instead of `window.open` use `window.location.href` for redirection as muzzafar mentioned.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me in IE10 . Specifically the line window.event.returnValue=false;

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.location.href this should work fine in the redirection.

Example:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';" />
```

Moreover, using it on keyup is a better option.

Comment: Thanks. But wish to know more on why it happens.